# Is there anyway to fake a cron job with PHP and JS/Ajax?

Tags: php, cron

My webhost recently updated something that has shut down the abblity to run cron jobs for an as of yet undefined amount of time. Which wouldn't be a problem, save for the fact that two hours before they did, I had released my project for beta testing.

I've currently got a tab open on my computer with some script on my local server that is updating the live server via an autorefresher. however, I don't feel it would be a good idea to keep my laptop running 24/7 until they fix this error. so I was wondering if there is any wya possible to "Fake" a cron job in php?

Comment: Can you set the cron job on another server/webhost?

Comment: you can have one run that is triggered by a visit to the website, but you do need to have visitors so it does not always run if your site is not that busy.

Comment: at this current moment the only server/webhost is the one that is currently unable to run cron jobs. @Shomz